# Swipe down in recycler view when recycler view is at 0 position i.e has not started scrolling

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

turn on the visibility of search layout when recycler view is pulled down and when recycler view is at the 0th position i.e has not started scrolling yet and want to hide the search layout when recycler view starts scrolling.

Comment: Did you try any code, please share your code snippet?

Comment: I have tried gesture listener on recycler view when that is not working in this case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use CoordinatorLayout as your root view with

```
   app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"
```

set in your `SearchView`

and don't forget to set

```
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
```

in your `ScrollView` (in this case is `RecyclerView`)

Change your layout to this

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/overview_coordinator_layout"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:padding="0dp"
        app:elevation="0dp">

        <YourSearchView
            android:id="@+id/shadowToolbar"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>


    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: This is not working. Getting a callback in this when the recycler view starts scrolling. But I want to turn on the visibility when the recycler is at 0 position and is pulled down

Comment: it is working when I started scrolling downwards and then I start scrolling upwards and I reach the first position. But I dont want to show the search layout in this case. I want to show it when user pulls down after recycler view stops and is at its initial state.

Comment: I am not using AppBarLayout because there is a header which has many other views along with the search layout. I dont have to hide other views but only search layout. I am attaching the image. So when recycler view is at 0 position and is pulled down I want to show the search layout and when recycler view starts scrolling I want to hide that.

Comment: Keep your other views in header as it should be and put your searchview in appbarlayout

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215977/discussion-between-pratishtha-sharma-and-hai-hack).

Comment: is everything ok?

Comment: yes Hai Hack. Thanks alot for your help. I have accepted your answer as the correct one. Thanks alot .